# How can I query my HTML using this jQuery expression?

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm processing HTML and I need to query a particular subset of it, but I only know how to do this easily with jQuery selectors.

Here's my PHP code:

```
$words = array('word');        
$baseUrl = 'http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val='; //word goes at the end        
$resultIndex = 0;

foreach($words as $word) {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$word]))
        continue;
    $contents = file_get_contents($baseUrl . urldecode(utf8_decode($_REQUEST[$word])));

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK! HOW DO I WRITE THIS IN PHP
    $dataineed = $contents.find(".ul a").attr("href"); 

    $contents = preg_replace('/(search?[\d\w]+)/','http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/',     $contents);

    echo "<div id='results' style='
      //style
     ", (++$resultIndex) ,"'>", $dataineed, $contents,
        "</div>";
}
```

The query I would use in jQuery is this:

```
.find(".ul a").attr("href")
```

How can I write that using PHP and DOM?

Comment: If you're asking this question you seem to be be missing the point. jQuery is front-end, PHP is backend. What are you trying to do?

Comment: do you try to convert? passing variable? or what?

Comment: @elclanrs I need to save the HREF values of the links (a) inside every ul from $contents. The variable should be printed in PHP.

Comment: @Charlie exactly, convert

Comment: @LaPelotaNoSeMancha Charlie is asking you what you've tried.

Comment: Well that `href` comes from PHP, you have access to it. Just store the values before printing the content. Without code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @Daedalus i am sorry not to know as much as you guys, I am jus t starting programming. If you could include the solution/example for me that would be great.

Comment: @LaPelotaNoSeMancha Show us what you've tried first.

Comment: @LaPelotaNoSeMancha you can `POST` it, or using `Ajax' or using 'PHP DOMDocument';

Comment: I don't think many understood what you were trying to do, so I've edited the question and voted to reopen it. Hope others will pick up on it as well.

Comment: It's better now. I didn't quite get your question. XPath seems like the best option.

Comment: @elclanrs should i include the code below in the same php.file i am using? in separate tags?

Comment: If you have a question, add a a comment to an answer that comes closest to solving the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Using XPath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($contents);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

$dataineed = $xp->query('//*[contains(concat(" ",@class," ")," ul ")]//a')
    ->item(0)
    ->getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: I wish I knew as much as you

Comment: @LaPelotaNoSeMancha I'm glad that your first question was not a regular expression to parse html ;-)